# Mixed-design with split-plot and mixed effect

Tags: anova, mixed-model, experiment-design, terminology, split-plot

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance):

> a **mixed-design** analysis of variance model (also known as a **split-plot** ANOVA) is used to test for differences between two or more independent groups whilst subjecting participants to repeated measures. Thus, in a mixed-design ANOVA model, one factor (a fixed effects factor) is a between-subjects variable and the other (a random effects factor) is a within-subjects variable. Thus, overall, the model is a type of **mixed effect model**.

My questions:

1. What relation is between mixed design and split-plot
   design?  Is a split-plot design a within-subject design, or a between-subject design, or both?
2. Why is the model of a mixed design a mixed effect model? Which input variable has random
   effect and which input variable has fixed effect?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure terminology varies, but I think it's fair to say that a *split-plot* design (where there are two or more treatments imposed at different hierarchical levels) is a specific example of a mixed design. Mixed effect models (also called multilevel or hierarchical models; repeated measures are another special case) are so-called because they include both random and fixed effect terms.

I would say that split-plot designs are "both" between- and within-subject designs, because (at least) one treatment is between- and (at least) one treatment is within-subject.

In order to answer the other question one would need a more specific example.

Comment: +1 but I think one can answer Q2 as well: both between- and within- factors are treated as fixed, whereas the plot id (aka subject id) is a grouping variable that is treated as random.